# Reason for this output of stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to learn stringstream and I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream os;
    os.str("Purohit");
    os << "Vipul" << endl;
    cout << os.str() << endl;
}
```

When I compile it and run it, I get the following output:

```
Vipul
t
```

Why? Shouldn't this output Purohit Vipul?

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to just initialize it with the string.

Comment: @chris What do you mean by that? And also, can you explain why is it happening?

Comment: `stringstream os("Purohit");`. Simple as that, except `std::ostringstream` should be used since you're only using `operator<<` on it. Anyway, I'm sure there's an explanation on the workings of `str` *somewhere* on here. Multiple, actually.

Comment: @chris doesn't seem to work that way.. with only `stringstream os("Purohit");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `str` method replaces the content of `stringstresm`, without placing the buffer pointer for the subsequent writes at the end of the stream. That is why when you output `"Vipul\n"` it writes over the `"Purohit"` string that you placed into the stream earlier:

Initial state

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
P u r o h i t
^
```

After the `<<` write:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5  6
V i p u l \n t
```

You could call `seekg` to set the position before appending the `"Vipul"` string, but an easier fix would be to use `<<` for both writes.

Comment: +++ for the illustration

Comment: thanks, it works fine. one question though, when we enter a new element in stringstream, it always writes a new line, right? so I can't output them in the same line.

Comment: @user2943407, It only inserts a newline if you have a newline in what you insert.

Comment: @user2943407 Your code controls newline: you get it only when you write `\n` or `endl`.